# How can I make the teilen method use one of the integers to run the method?

Tags: arrays, while-loop

I want to run the teilen method with integers from the arrray. With each of the integers once. Unfortuantely it seems like it doesn't know which number of the integer to use.
Does anyone know how to solve that?

```
public class While {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] intArray = {17458, 10, 6};
   
        teilen(intArray[0]);
    }
    
    public static void teilen(int[] intArray){
        while (intArray[] >= 10){
            new intArray[] = intArray/2;
        }
    
        System.out.println(intArray[]);
    }
    
}
```

I tried to run the teilen method with intArray[0] with the hope that it would take the first integer from the array. This is what I get:

```
While.java:10: error: '.class' expected
        while (intArray[] >= 10){
                          ^
While.java:11: error: array dimension missing
            new intArray[] = intArray[]/2;
                           ^
While.java:11: error: '.class' expected
            new intArray[] = intArray[]/2;
                                       ^
While.java:14: error: '.class' expected
        System.out.println(intArray[]);
```

Comment: I would recommend adding "java" to your tags to help the search algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say if you want to do anything other than simply print out the new values, so here is how to do that:

```java
public class While {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] intArray = {17458, 10, 6};

        for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) 
            teilen(intArray[i]);
    }

    public static void teilen(int value){
        double newValue = value/2;
        System.out.println(newValue);
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using a double as the output value, since using an integer would fail for any odd input value.